# Yii2 multiple paginations

Tags: yii, yii2

How to use multiple paginations in controller ?
I encountered the following error.

Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\LinkPager::expertpagination

in controller :

```
$count=$query_comment->count();
$pagination=new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count, 'defaultPageSize' => 2]);
$models_comment = $query_comment->offset($pagination->offset)
      ->limit($pagination->limit)
      ->all();
      $count_expert=$query_expert->count();
$expertpagination=new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count_expert, 'defaultPageSize' => 2]);
$models_expert = $query_expert->offset($expertpagination->offset)
      ->limit($expertpagination->limit)
      ->asArray()->all();
return $this->render('product',['id'=>$id,
            'table_name' => $table_name ,
            'models2'=>$models2,
            'models3'=>$models3,
            'pagination'=>$pagination,
            'expertpagination'=>$expertpagination,
            'models_comment' => $models_comment ,
            'model_expert' => $model_expert ,
            'models_expert' => $models_expert
        ]);
```

Comment: show your view code  .. too

Comment: <?php
 echo LinkPager::widget([
      'expertpagination' => $expertpagination,
   ]);
?>
and 
<?php
   echo LinkPager::widget([
      'pagination' => $pagination,
   ]);
?>

Comment: you could update your question and ad  the code  .. in comment the si not readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property always has the same name  is the content that change then:

```
      <?php 
            echo LinkPager::widget([ 'pagination' => $expertpagination, ]); 
      ?>
```

and

```
      <?php 
              echo LinkPager::widget([ 'pagination' => $pagination, ]);
       ?>
```